# I am using community edition IntelliJ and my build.gradle.kts file is generating an error - I can't tell what's wrong with it

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea, dependencies

```
dependencies {     
   testImplementation(platform("org.junit:junit-bom:5.9.1"))     
   testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter")     
   compileOnly("com.ibm.maximo:asset-management:7.6.0.0")     
   compileOnly("com.ibm.maximo:asset-management-webclient:7.6.0.0")     
   compileOnly("org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.2")     
   compileOnly("javax.j2ee:j2ee:1.4")     
   //implementation(files("C:/Users/jkish/eclipseworkspace/bia/lib/build/httpclient.jar"))
}
```

The error is:

[image]

Comment: sorry I'm on my Mac and I couldn't get the body of the question to format correctly - I tried replacing, as the error message implies, Java with javaxj2ee but that did not improve things.

Comment: For the formatting issue, it comes from the use of the ' character instead of  the ` character

Comment: Do you get the same error when building by Gradle form the command line: `./gradlew build`?

Comment: Try [googling](https://www.google.com/search?q=gradle+inconsistent+module+metadata+found&oq=inconsisten+gradle+metadat&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUqCAgBEAAYFhgeMgYIABBFGDkyCAgBEAAYFhgeMggIAhAAGBYYHjIICAMQABgWGB4yCAgEEAAYFhge0gEIODgyM2owajSoAgCwAgA&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) about this error for the solutions. Also try deleting Gradle caches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the POM of javax.j2ee:j2ee:1.4 at https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/j2ee/j2ee/1.4/j2ee-1.4.pom you see that it says `group` is `javax` which is inconsistent with the group used to resolve it, i.e.
`javax.j2ee`, and that is what Gradle complains about and aborts with failure. This artifact is simply pushed in a bad, broken state.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there was some sort of issue with Maven and after some generous assistance from others I found this worked:

compileOnly("milyn:j2ee:1.4")